# Adding Timescaledb extension in postgres db in window cannot found timescaledb.control error

Tags: timescaledb

adding timescaledb extension in postgresql db by following command in windows.

Command: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb;

Error: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/timescaledb.control": No such file or directory

Tried to do setup again for postgresql and timescale db but it did not happen. Could see the file at path 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\share\extension\timescaledb.control' any way to setup on the error path.

output for pg_config:

```
BINDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/bin
DOCDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/doc
HTMLDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/doc
INCLUDEDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/include
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/include/server
LIBDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/lib
PKGLIBDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/lib
LOCALEDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/share/locale
MANDIR = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/man
SHAREDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/10/share
SYSCONFDIR = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/etc
PGXS = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = --enable-thread-safety --enable-nls --with-ldap --with-openssl --with-ossp-uuid --with-libxml --with-libxslt --with-icu --with-tcl --with-perl --with-python
CC = not recorded
CPPFLAGS = not recorded
CFLAGS = not recorded
CFLAGS_SL = not recorded
LDFLAGS = not recorded
LDFLAGS_EX = not recorded
LDFLAGS_SL = not recorded
LIBS = not recorded
VERSION = PostgreSQL 10.11
```

Comment: It's pretty strange that you have Postgres for windows installed, yet the extension is searched for in a Unix-like path. Can you share some more details on how you installed postgres? Or share your output from pg_config?

Comment: I downloaded from here - https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads version 10.11, windows x86-64.

Comment: Facing the same issue, were you able to solve it?